# How to recognize mounted media only in ubuntu VM in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virus

In many of schools in Turkey there is a virus and you can easily get just by plugging in a flash drive. It's like a joke virus but it's annoying. Anyway... linux is not affected by this virus so when I need a file in my flash drive I turn on my Lubuntu desktop pc and get what I need from my Windows 10 laptop using smb protocol.

I want to do this on a single computer. I also don't want to dualboot my laptop. 
It's problematic I've tried.

So my idea is when I mount a flash drive -which is affected by this virus or not- I want this flash drive can't be accessed and readed by Windows 10 but I want to access via VM. So virus is not going to be affect my windows and I can access my files in VM.

Is it possible? If yes how can I do it? Thanks already!

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox? If so you should be able to set up filters to automatically share the drive with the VM. This is explained [here](https://www.htpcbeginner.com/access-usb-drive-in-virtualbox-guest-os/) (`VirtualBox Mount USB with Filters`).

Comment: @xenoid yes I'm using VirtualBox but the main idea is; I don't want windows to see my flash drive

Comment: According to that page it won't...